# How to find the distinct values of a column and find the sum of those same values of another column?

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, datatable

In my c# WinForm application, I have a `DataTable` keeping track of sales of fruits and it's like:

```
/*TableA*/
Name | QuantitySold
Apple | 5
Orange | 10
Apple | 3
Grape | 2
Banana | 6
Orange | 7
Apple | 2
Grape | 2
```

Now I want to filter them by the same fruit names AND get the sums of each of those fruits sold at the same time, creating a new resultant `DataTable`, which should look like

```
/*TableB*/
Name | TotalSold
Apple | 10
Orange | 17
Grape | 4
Banana | 6
```

How could I achieve this? 
I have found the count of distinct fruit names by

```
int distinctCt = TableA.AsEnumerable()
               .Select(row=>row.Field<string>("Name"))
               .Distinct().Count();
```

But I realized this won't go anywhere from here.
Can someone please give me an idea on how to do this?

Comment: Look up `GroupBy`, that will help you more than `Distinct`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `GroupBy` and `Sum`:

```
var nameGroups = TableA.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(r => r.Field<string>("Name"));
var TableB = TableA.Clone();
TableB.Columns["QuantitySold"].ColumnName = "TotalSold";

foreach(var g in nameGroups)
{
    TableB.Rows.Add(g.Key, g.Sum(r => r.Field<int>("QuantitySold")));
}
```

Comment: Omg it works like a charm. One day I want to be able to write a code snippet as fast as you can. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use GroupBy, try this:

```
var x = TableA.AsEnumerable()
        .GroupBy(r=>r.Field<string>("Name"))
        .Select(sm => new 
            {
                Name = sm.First().Field<string>("Name"),
                QuamtitySold = sm.Sum(q => q.Field<int>("QuantitySold"))
            });
```